# Unit test in Unity - Getting an InvalidCastException - Why? And how to fix?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, unity-game-engine, nunit

I try to be as specific and helpful as possible in my questions here on S.O. but for this one, well, that means almost nothing, as I have absolutely no hint of the faintest clue about why this is happening.

It happens on any/every test (even "blank" ones). And I already tried (uninstalling and) updating unity. - Didn't work.

Anyways, here is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
2017.11.16 14:54:24.308   ERROR System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'NUnit.Engine.CallbackHandler' no tipo 'System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler'.
   em NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController.LoadTestsAction..ctor(FrameworkController controller, Object handler)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)
   em System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   em System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   em System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   em System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   em System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
   em NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Load(String testAssemblyPath, IDictionary`2 settings)
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.LoadPackage()
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load()
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.LoadPackage()
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.EnsurePackageIsLoaded()
   em NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.NUnit.Engine.ITestRunner.Explore(TestFilter filter)
   em JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.BuiltInNUnitRunner.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RunTests>b__0()
   em JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.BuiltInNUnitRunner.WithExtensiveErrorHandling(IRemoteTaskServer server, Action action)
```

---

This is making me pretty much code without (unit-)testing for the last couple of days, so if anyone has any idea about the cause and/or solutions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the [Unity Test Runner](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html) instead of running them through Resharper/Rider/VS.

Comment: @EvilTak Was one of the first things I tried, but did it again just to be safe. It gives me pretty much the same exception; trims a couple of lines related to ReSharper's NUnit runner. What's the difference though? Either worked before.

Comment: Which version of the NUnit framework are you compiling against - v2 or v3?

Comment: @Chris Unity 2017's... I believe it's V3 or "V3-equivalent".

Answer (score 2):

Resharper is using the NUnit Engine to run tests But the engine only supports tests written against .NET 2.0 through 4.5. The framework you are using is one of the .NET Standard builds. I can tell this by looking at the stack trace and seeing that it doesn't have a reference to System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.

You should be able to run your tests in Test Explorer using the latest installation of the NUnit 3 VS Test Adapter.

Updating for clarity...

There's no doubt that are using a version of the nunit framework that is not supported by the platform. That's the key here.

Some builds of the framework use `System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler`(.NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5) while others (.NET Standard 1.3 and 1.6) do not. Since NUnit is looking for that interface, you are referencing one of the builds that uses it. Since it's not available, you are on a platform that doesn't include it.

A simple workaround would be for you to define the interface yourself, duplicating it exactly as defined by Microsoft. You don't have to implement it, since the framework you are using does that. Of course, that could lead to other failures due to framework / platform incompatibility so it's probably better to resolve the compatibility issue in the first place.

Unfortunately, I can't be of any help on the Unity side of the problem.

Comment: That would be strange, as I was able to do unit testing without any problems before it suddenly started reporting the tests as inconclusive and giving that exception. But I've seen enough weird s___ in programming to almost never discard such possibilities; specially so when I have no other lead anyway. I'll try the adapter, and if that fails, some other stuff based on the tip, and will report back ASAP. For now, here, have a cookie (+1). =)

Comment: Yea... That didn't work. Whatever the problem is, I don't think it's version mismatch, because 1) Unit tests used to work. 2) Noone else seems to be getting this problem (I'd expect it to be happening all over, if it was indeed such version mismatch). And 3) Test adapter didn't work; I still get the exact same exception.

Comment: Strange indeed. Here's what I can tell you... 1) the missing interface method is only used by the NUnit v3 driver that is part of the engine 2) that interface and method is not available in some platforms. What is the platform of your test?

Comment: I'm testing on PC (windows 10 64-bit), and attempted deployment settings for both Standalone (windows) and android. Both fail with the exception. I am not sure about which deployment platform I had when unit-testing was working (at least one worked; possibly/probably both), but I think it should/normally does work on both, as I don't see any other Unity3D developer having problems with this.

Comment: BTW: I formatted my PC and reinstalled unity from scratch, so see if this would somehow fix things... It didn't... So now I'm even more clueless about what's wrong. I'm starting to get paranoid and think that Unity 2017.* versions (opposed to Unity 5.6.4.*f3 -  The last version I can be sure to remember unit-testing was working) have broken/bugged unit-test/NUnit.

Comment: I have the very same issue so at least you are not alone in this

Comment: I clarified my answer since the mismatch of nunit framework build an platform is so clear to me and didn't seem to be getting across in the original answer.